# Google Map app fails to open web link on mobile devices

Tags: ios, mobile, browser, maps, direction

I have this link in a web page:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=-27.360198,153.017331
```

It works fine on desktop, but on mobile, I get redirected to the Google Maps app and it displays "Unsupported link"

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem on Android, I solved it switching from this link:

```
("https://www.google.com/maps?daddr="+address, _blank);
```

to this one:

```
("https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+address, _blank);
```